# Rails 5.1, Errno::EMFILE: Too many open files - getcwd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, factory-bot

I've started seeing this error in the past couple of days when running my entire /spec directory. I doubt it is revealing anything about the state of my tests - it occurs randomly. My hunch is it might be a configuration issue in `rails_helper.rb`.

```
 Errno::EMFILE:
   Too many open files - getcwd
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:115:in `expand_path'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:115:in `path'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:146:in `exists?'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:95:in `size'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:137:in `empty?'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:131:in `cache!'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:329:in `cache'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:163:in `attachment='
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-base64-2.5.3/lib/carrierwave/base64/adapter.rb:26:in `block in mount_base64_uploader'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `public_send'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:33:in `association'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `block in define_attribute'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:33:in `association'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `block in define_attribute'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:33:in `association'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `block in define_attribute'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:33:in `association'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:77:in `block in define_attribute'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
 # /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
```

The stack trace is always the same. I can't see anywhere explicitly in my code where a file is being opened.

I'd recently implemented DatabaseCleaner with the following options:

```
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before(:each) do
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    RedisCache.new.flushdb
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

They had this problem connected with `Carrierwave 0.5.8`.

The [post](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/313) is from 14/Mar/2012 so it is for sure outdated

> I can confirm that carrierwave up until 0.5.7 works correctly. Only 0.5.8 causes this problem. I'm going to open an issue in carrierwave later tonight.

But you have `Carrierwave 0.11.2`